# Creating timecode from frames

Tags: javascript, string, time, formatting

I have a FPS (frames per second) of 30. I have a total FPS so far, lets say 1020. I want to display this as a formatted timecode, as below.

```
var fps = 30;
var currentFrame = 1020;

var resultString = ; // HH:MM:SS:FF
```

Are there any Javascript functions built in for formatting like this?

To be clear, I need the string to be formatted as such: HH:MM:SS:FF

Comment: What's your timecode mode? Are you concerned about drop frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var fps = 30;
    var currentFrame = 169;
    var SS = Math.floor(currentFrame / fps);
    var MM = Math.floor(SS / 60);
    var HH = Math.floor(MM / 60);
    var FF = currentFrame - (SS * fps);

    function pad(str, width, what, left) {
        str = String(str);
        what = String(what);
        var w = width - str.length;

        if (left) {
            return (new Array(w + 1)).join(what) + str;
        } else {
            return str + (new Array(w + 1)).join(what);
        }
    }

    var i,
        timecode = [HH, MM, SS, FF];

    for (i = 0; i < timecode.length; i += 1) {
        timecode[i] = pad(timecode[i], 2, 0, true);
    }

    var resultString = timecode.join(':'); // HH:MM:SS:FF
```

Comment: Very nice - I have noticed one oddity here, when you have a currentFrame of 169 it shows  00:00:06:-11 with a minus? Any ideas?

Comment: This is perfect, and very helpful to more than me. Wish I could upvote more. :)

Comment: If you're wondering the error was coming from the use of Math.round instead of Math.floor

Comment: SS MM and HH will actually have total seconds, minutes and hours.  

For example, 1 hour time will become [1, 60, 3600, FF]

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for a *built-in* JS function?..

```
var FF = currentFrame % fps;
var seconds = (currentFrame - FF) / fps;
var SS = seconds % 60;
var minutes = (seconds - SS) / 60;
var MM = minutes % 60;
var HH = (minutes - MM) / 60;
```

There you go.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Would you be able to expand on this, I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: % is a modulo division operator, so we extract the whole part and the remainder at each step.

Comment: And because of the % it's nicer than using Math.floor

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in much simpler way:

```
function displayTime(currentFrame) {
    var fps = 30;
    var h = Math.floor(currentFrame/(60*60*fps));
    var m = (Math.floor(currentFrame/(60*fps))) % 60;
    var s = (Math.floor(currentFrame/fps)) % 60;
    var f = currentFrame % fps;
    return showTwoDigits(h) + ":" + showTwoDigits(m) + ":" + showTwoDigits(s) + ":" + showTwoDigits(f);
}

function showTwoDigits(number) {
    return ("00" + number).slice(-2);
}

console.log("Frame 1020 will be displayed as " + displayTime(1020));
```

*Frame 1020 will be displayed as 00:00:34:00*

**showTwoDigits**
This help function takes a number (example: 6), adds "00" before it, which makes it a string (example: "006"). Then it slices back 2 positions from the end (will give "06").

**displayTime**
**var h**
It calculates hours by dividing the frames by 60*60*30 frames per hours. An hour has 60*60*30 frames. 
**var m**
Minutes are calculated in the same way by dividing it by 60*30 frames per minute. But note here that this could result in a number like 80 minutes, because it is the TOTAL amount of minutes. The script has to take in account only the remainder after dividing this amount by 60. Here the modulus comes into play. 80 % 60 will give 20, the number we are looking for. 
**var s**
In a similar way the seconds are calculated by dividing the frames by 30 frames per second and then take it modulus 60 (so that 65 seconds will be represented as 5).

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the date object see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Just make something like:

```
var d = new Date( yourframetime + new Date().getTime() );
var str = d.getHours()+':'+ d.getMinutes()+ ':' + d.getSeconds() + .......
```

than you can use all the string functions of the object, or make your own with it.

Comment: To be clear, I need the string to be formatted as such: HH:MM:SS:FF

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I was using this recently and a combination of Alexander's and Lucas's code give the correct results.  The checked version actually breaks on really large frame counts ( I think due to Math.floor).

Code is:

```
var fps = 30;
var currentFrame = 169;
var FF = currentFrame % fps;
var seconds = (currentFrame - FF) / fps;
var SS = seconds % 60;
var minutes = (seconds - SS) / 60;
var MM = minutes % 60;
var HH = (minutes - MM) / 60;

function pad(str, width, what, left) {
    str = String(str);
    what = String(what);
    var w = width - str.length;

    if (left) {
        return (new Array(w + 1)).join(what) + str;
    } else {
        return str + (new Array(w + 1)).join(what);
    }
}

var i,
    timecode = [HH, MM, SS, FF];

for (i = 0; i < timecode.length; i += 1) {
    timecode[i] = pad(timecode[i], 2, 0, true);
}

var resultString = timecode.join(':'); // HH:MM:SS:FF
```

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone interested with the swift version of the showTwoDigits function, here is a working code sample:

```
func showTwoDigits(number:Float) -> (String){
        var string = ("00" + String(format:"%.f", number))
        var range = Range(start: (advance(string.endIndex, -2)), end: string.endIndex)
        var cutStr = string.substringWithRange(range)
        return cutStr
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function converts to `HH:MM:SS:FF` correctly :

```
var convertTime = function (frames, fps) {
    fps = (typeof fps !== 'undefined' ?  fps : 30 );
    var pad = function(input) {return (input < 10) ? "0" + input : input;},
        seconds = (typeof frames !== 'undefined' ?  frames / fps : 0 );
    return [
        pad(Math.floor(seconds / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(seconds % 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(frames % fps))
    ].join(':');
}
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var convertTime = function (frames, fps) {
    fps = (typeof fps !== 'undefined' ?  fps : 30 );
    var pad = function(input) {return (input < 10) ? "0" + input : input;},
        seconds = (typeof frames !== 'undefined' ?  frames / fps : 0 );
    return [
        pad(Math.floor(seconds / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(seconds % 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(frames % fps))
    ].join(':');
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify({
    5 : convertTime(5),
    50 : convertTime(50),
    126 : convertTime(126),
    1156 : convertTime(1156),
    9178 : convertTime(9178),
    13555 : convertTime(13555)
}, null, '\t') +  '</pre>';
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zx78ngq7/1/).